# How to add headers in MySQL above sets of data

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Headers might be the wrong word but if I have a table of shifts for a job and a table of customers I'm trying to figure out how to select a row displaying the customer information in between customers.

[Shift Table]
shift_id, customer_id, date

[Shift_Needs_Workers]
id, shift_id, people_id (nullable = true)

[Customers]
customer_id, customer_name

Customers can have multiple shifts and Shifts can have multiple workers needed
I'm wanting to run a SELECT statement that can output

```
Customer A
Shift 1, Worker 1
Shift 1, Worker 2
Shift 2, Worker 1
Shift 2, Worker 2
Shift 2, Worker 3
Customer B
Shift 1, Worker 1
Shift 2, Worker 2
etc
```

I looked into with rollup but that seems to need something to group by and I'm the opposite I want all the rows but then an extra one.  I looked into Union but it looked like it was one additional query or multiple separate queries and I want to "union" in the middle of my queries where the customer_id changes.

Any help or other links that might help would be awesome.

Comment: This is much better done in an application programming language, not the database.

Comment: @Barmar, do you have any suggestions on report builders that I could point at our MySQL server and have people other than our dev team be able to make these kinds of reports up?  I do agree with you and I have built many of our reports using PHP vs straight sql but I need more extensability for the company.

Comment: No, sorry, I use PHP for all my development, not report builders.

Answer (score 1):

You could build your reports with jasper reports. You would create one main report for the customers and a subreport for the shift information.

If you want to do it in one statement, you would first have to generate a structure like this

```
CustomerA, null, null, 0
CustomerA, Shift1, Worker1, 1
CustomerA, Shift1, Worker2, 1
CustomerB, null, null, 0
```

The last column is the level of the information.
After you have this structure, which you can easily generate using unions and joins
you can generate an output column with a case or if then else

```
case levelNr when 0 then customer_name else concat(shift_id, ' ', worker_id) end
```

Comment: Thank you!! I just looked into Jasper and think that is definitely the way I want to go.  For the OP question, I'm struggling with the specific joins and unions to use.  I'm not sure how to get the data structured with the "null,null,0" part in between each customer.  Is there a mysql foreach method that I'm not aware of for using the union statement.